# How to get al the combinations of the elements of a vector in R?

Tags: r

I need to get all the combinations of n elements that can be built using a vector that contains N elements.  `expand.grid()` does not work because I don't care the order in which the elements are dragged, and 1 element cannot be selected twice.

For example all the possible combinations of two elements of the vector`c(1,2,3,4,5)` are

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
2,3
2,4
2,5
3,4
3,5
4,5
```

Comment: Use `t(combn(1:5, 2))`

Comment: had the same answer as above but if you want those commas as well you can use: `apply(t(combn(1:5,2)),1,paste,collapse=",")`

Comment: `combn` has a `FUN=` argument too, so `combn(1:5, 2, paste, collapse=",")`